# Is it safe to access layer object(e.g. QgsVectorLayer) in background task(QgsTask) in QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I was confused if it's safe for developers to access `QgsVectorLayer` in a background task(`QgsTask`), like reading data from layers?

Because descriptions in PyQGIS cookbook are different with different versions.

In [version 3.16](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html), it says:

*Any background task (regardless of how it is created) must NEVER use any `QObject` that lives on the main thread, `such as accessing QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject` or perform any GUI based operations like creating new widgets or interacting with existing widgets. Qt widgets must only be accessed or modified from the main thread. Data that is used in a task must be copied before the task is started. Attempting to use them from background threads will result in crashes.*

In [version 3.4](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html), it doesn't mention that we can't use `QgsVectorLayer`.

*Any background task (regardless of how it is created) must NEVER perform any GUI based operations, such as creating new widgets or interacting with existing widgets. Qt widgets must only be accessed or modified from the main thread. Attempting to use them from background threads will result in crashes.*

If we can use layer object in `QgsTask`, it's very convenient to read data, such as

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression( ' "Counties" = \'ABC\' ' )

features = layer.getFeatures( request )
```

And from my testing on QGIS3.4, it's ok to access `QgsVectorLayer` without errors.

If we can't access layer object in background tasks, how do tools in toolbox handle this case because they run in the background?